# How to use naive bayes classifier after Extract the features using TF_IDF

Tags: python, classification, nltk, sentiment-analysis, naivebayes

I'm Trying to classify features using Naive Bayes classifier, I used TF_IDF for feature extraction.

The `finaltfidfVector` is a list of vectors, each vector represents list of numbers, `0` if the word not found, else the weight of word if it found.

And `classlabels` contains all class label for each vector. I'm trying to classify it with this code but it doesn't work.

26652 lines for Dataset

```
from nltk.classify import apply_features

def naivebyse(finaltfidfVector,classlabels,reviews):

    train_set = []
    j = 0
    for vector in finaltfidfVector:
        arr={}
        if j<18697:
            arr[tuple(vector)] = classlabels[j]
            train_set.append((arr, reviews[j]))
            j += 1

    test_set = []
    j = 18697
    for vector in finaltfidfVector:
        arr = {}
        if j < 26652 and j>=18697:
            arr[tuple(vector)] = classlabels[j]
            test_set.append((arr, reviews[j]))
            j += 1

    classifier = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(train_set)
    print(nltk.classify.accuracy(classifier, test_set))
```

The output :

```
0.0
```

The used ***reference for TF_IDF and applied on `finaltfidfVector`*** https://triton.ml/blog/tf-idf-from-scratch?fbclid=IwAR3UlCToGYFEQSmugXo3M5Q9fcld79JfXSfBaDG7wKv5a49O0ZDEft9DFNg. 
data set

[this is sample about the used data set before preprocessing and TF_IDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eG0te.png)

This is sample for the first vector for index of zero in `finaltfidfVector` list

```
[0.0,0.0, 0.0, 0.6214608098422192, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5115995809754083,0.0,0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5521460917862246, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.6214608098422192,0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.6214608098422192, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.6214608098422192]
```

`classlabels` contains class label for each vector 
, 1 for sarcasm 0 for not sarcasm. The class label of index 0 is 1, this 1 for the first vector in `finaltfidfVector`.

The first item for **train_set** is

`({(0.0, 0.0, 1.3803652294655615,.....ect): '0'}, "former versace store clerk sues over secret 'black code' for minority shoppers")`

Comment: Can you post how you created `finaltfidfVector ` and `classlabels`? Preferably show some of the data.

Comment: Done,is there anything else?

Comment: I have modified my post.

Comment: Can you reformat your post and provide a minimal, runnable code snippet example? I tried to reproduce your problem but your `naivebayes` function has syntax error. Please fix that and post related code again.

Comment: Can you tell me where exactly the error is? , I am really disappointed.

Comment: I want to help, but. Considering too much information missing in this post, I just cannot simply reproduce your problem. Either you should rephrase your post, with **reproducible code** and **minimal data**; or I suggest you follow a tutorial on nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier first, you should be able to find them on Google.

Comment: Take time to read this tutorial about how to ask a [mcve question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Is this modification good?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a reproducible toy example:

```
# let's define a train_set
train_set = [
    ({'adam': 0.05,'is': 0.0, 'a': 0.0, 'good': 0.02, 'man': 0.0}, 1),
    ({'eve': 0.0, 'is':  0.0, 'a':  0.0,'good':  0.02,'woman': 0.0}, 1),
    ({'adam': 0.05, 'is': 0.0, 'evil': 0.0}, 0)]
```

The toy data set is created using a handcrafted "tfidf" score dictionary:

```
tfidf_dict = {
 'adam': 0.05,
 'eve': 0.05,
 'evil': 0.02,
 'kind': 0.02,
 'good': 0.02,
 'bad': 0.02
}
```

Where each known word has a tfidf score, and an unknow word has score 0. And also in train_set we have positive score for the sentence labeled by 1 ("adam is good"), and negative labeled by 0 ("adam is evil").

Now run some test:

```
import nltk
clf = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(train_set)
```

See how this works on toy train set:

```
>>> nltk.classify.accuracy(clf, train_set)
1.0
```

Since test set has the same structure as train set, this is sufficient to show how you can train and run a naive bayes classifier.

Comment: OK , i will try this

Comment: @AsmaaAbd_El3al that's not related to this specific post and I'll close the following up. Ask a new question for your next problem.

Comment: @AsmaaAbd_El3al If my post has ever been helpful, consider upvoting will be appreciated. Or if it's not, here's all I can do for this one.